# C# DataGridView with DataSet display issue

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataset

I have the following code:

```
private void Timer1Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  timer_ScanTimer.Enabled = false;

  var psc = new ParseScannedCheckNumbers();
  if (psc.ParseCheck(_checkData))
  {
    label_Status.Text = @"Scan Next Check";

    var ct = checkTrans.IndividualCheck.NewIndividualCheckRow();
    ct.Date = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
    var bracct = GetBranchAccountNumber(psc.BankAccountNumber);
    if (bracct.Trim().Length == 7)
    {
      ct.Branch = bracct.Substring(0, 2);
      ct.AccountNumber = bracct.Substring(2, 5);
      ct.NameOnCheck = GetAccountName(ct.Branch + ct.AccountNumber);
      ct.AccountBalance = GetAccountBalance(ct.Branch + ct.AccountNumber);
    }
    else
    {
      ct.Branch = Configuration.Branch;
      ct.AccountNumber = string.Empty;
      ct.NameOnCheck = string.Empty;
      ct.AccountBalance = 0;
    }

    ct.CheckAmount = 0;
    ct.BankRoutingNumber = psc.BankRoutingNumber;
    ct.BankAccountNumber = psc.BankAccountNumber;
    ct.CheckNumber = psc.CheckNumber;
    ct.Status = "Entered";
    checkTrans.IndividualCheck.Rows.Add(ct);
  }
  else
  {
    label_Status.Text = Resources.ScanCheck_ScanFailed;
  }
  _checkData = string.Empty;

  var rs = new RegistrySettings();
  if (!rs.ScanChecksContinuous)
  {
    StopScanning();
    label_Status.Text = Resources.ScanCheck_Success;
    EditLastRowEntered();
  }

  label_ChecksScanned.Text = (dgv_Checks.RowCount - 1).ToString();
}
```

When the timer goes off, I verified that I have received all of the data,  then I add it to the dataset.  It's being added to the dataset without issue, it's just being seen on the datagridview every time. Sometimes it works, most time it doesn't.

How do I get the datagridview to update when changes are done to the dataset? Am I doing something wrong in the above code?

Thanks! (again)

Comment: I tried dgv_Checks.Refresh(); but that didn't do anything for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you created the dataset and attached it to the `DataGridView` using the Visual Studio Data Source Configuration Wizard, then you probably have a call to

```
this.somethingTableAdapter.Fill(this.yourDataSet.someDataTable);
```

somewhere in your code. This is what actually loads the data from the `DataSet` into your `DataGridView`. While calling this method again might not be the 'proper' way to refresh your DGV, it did the job for me.